# Entity framework. Quering parent entity with subclass property loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

There is a simple domain..

```
public abstract class UserComment
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class BlogComment : UserComment
{
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoComment : UserComment
{
    public Photo Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Is there way to query all entities of type *UserComment* with properties Blog and Photo loaded?

```
var comment = DbContext.Set<UserComment>()
    .Include(x => x.Blog) // will not compile
    .Include(x => x.Photo) // will not compile
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (comment is PhotoComment )
{
    string url = (comment as PhotoComment).Photo.Url;
}
if (comment is BlogComment)
{
    var dateCreated = (comment as BlogComment).Blog.DateCreated;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should accept (mark as accepted) answers to your questions if they provide useful information (not to mention upvote). It is reward for people who answer your questions.

Comment: Where is this link located? I can't see any button or link called "Accept answer".

Comment: OK, now, I suppose it is not about code first? Did you try `comment.Blog.Load()` [explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896376.aspx)

Comment: I'm using code first. I looked to Load extensions, you mentioned. And found possible solution - cast parent class to child and use load extension: `context.Entry(comment as BlogComment).Reference(p => p.Blog).Load();`

Comment: You're welcome. One thing, do you have `using System.Data.Entity;`? Plain `.Include` should work with code first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will probably need two queries to get the result. If you only want the first element (`FirstOrDefault`) explicit loading - as you already proposed in the comments - is a good approach:

```
var comment = DbContext.Set<UserComment>().FirstOrDefault();

if (comment is BlogComment)
    DbContext.Entry(comment as BlogComment).Reference(bc => bc.Blog).Load();
else if (comment is PhotoComment)
    DbContext.Entry(comment as PhotoComment).Reference(pc => pc.Photo).Load();
```

If you want to load a list of `UserComment`s that's not the best solution as it would require to iterate over the loaded `UserComment`s and to call explicit loading for each element which will result in many queries.

For a list you can use the following approach that also will generate only two queries:

```
IEnumerable<UserComment> blogComments = DbContext.Set<UserComment>()
    .OfType<BlogComment>()
    .Include(bc => bc.Blog)
    .Cast<UserComment>()
    .AsEnumerable();

IEnumerable<UserComment> photoComments = DbContext.Set<UserComment>()
    .OfType<PhotoComment>()
    .Include(pc => pc.Photo)
    .Cast<UserComment>()
    .AsEnumerable();

List<UserComment> comments = blogComments.Concat(photoComments).ToList();
```

Because of the usage of `AsEnumerable()` this will run two separate database queries and concat the results to a single collection in memory.

LINQ-to-Entities supports `Cast` but for some reason it is not possible to remove the two `AsEnumerable()` conversions to get only a single database query and concat the results in the database. The code would still compile but I had a runtime exception about an invalid `Include` path.

I have tested with EF 4.1. It might be worth to test the query without `AsEnumerable()` with EF 5.0 to see if it still fails.